# select same table in multiple schema's without using union all

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.0

Schema Name's: `A,B`

Both schema have same Table :

Table Name: `stock`. Feilds `no,Stname`

I want retrive details from stock table in two schams.

So i use this query :

```
 select no,stname from A.stock union all select no,stname from B.stock
```

I want to get the tables detail with out union all. Is it possible ? How to do that ?

I am using postgresql 9.0

Comment: Can i ask you why you want to avoid `union all`?

Comment: @Houari Sir in my real if i am using its create a big query like my query size is 9 page in msword. if i connect the multiple schemas in single query is reduce the query in my project

Comment: What about creating a view that bring you those `union all` of all your stock tables, and in your project you have to just `select` query this view ?

Comment: i use select query only sir. And my some time my table have same no or  same stname. And how to use view in this case sir @Houari

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you view looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW union_of_my_stock_tables AS 
 select no,stname from A.stock 
 union all 
 select no,stname from B.stock;
union all 
 select no,stname from C.stock;
union all 
 select no,stname from D.stock;
```

And in your project you can query this view by:

```
select * from union_of_my_stock_tables;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. If i want my multiple tables combine in my query then i must create multiple view ah Sir?

Comment: How much cominaison do you have ?

Comment: i have more than 5 tables in multiple schema's

Comment: No, i'm talking about your combinaisons!?

Comment: Sorry sir i Can't understand?